# Pandas concat axis 1 failing(infinite loading)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to concat csv file and MA_3,MA_5 columns(they have NAN).
csv file  = https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-219dqlmhFA6-YtD8xRigo_ZVoAIJ21v/view?usp=sharing

code is this.

```
df = pd.read_csv('/content/mydrive/MyDrive/data/005930.KS.csv')

MA_3, MA_5  = pd.Series([]), pd.Series([])


for i, adj_close in enumerate(df['Adj Close']):
  MA_3 = MA_3.append(pd.Series([pd.Series.mean(ds['Adj Close'][i:i+3])]))
  MA_5 = MA_5.append(pd.Series([pd.Series.mean(ds['Adj Close'][i:i+5])]))
MA_3 = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame({'MA3':['','']}), MA_3.to_frame('MA3').iloc[:-2,:]])
MA_5 = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame({'MA5':['','','','']}), MA_5.to_frame('MA5').iloc[:-4,:]])
MA = pd.concat([MA_3, MA_5], axis=1, ignore_index=True)
df = pd.concat([df, MA], axis=1, ignore_index=True)
```

MA_3.shape is same as MA_5.shape but it doesn't work. It doesn't raise error but infinitely loading occurs.(axis=0 does work.) I want to solve this problem. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Testing your code I get an `InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects` error (no infinite loading).
The error occurs since the indices of the `MA_3` and `MA_5` dataframes are not unique. You can simply reset the indices before the `concat` operation:

```
MA_3.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
MA_5.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
MA = pd.concat([MA_3, MA_5], axis=1, ignore_index=True)
```

The option `drop=True` is set, so that the old indices (which are not required in this case) are not added as a new column.

**Note:** If I understand correctly, your goal is to add two columns with a running mean of `Adj Close` to your dataframe.  A simpler way to achieve this, is with using the pandas `rolling` function:

```
df = pd.read_csv(in_dir + file)
df['MA_3'] = df['Adj Close'].rolling(window=3).mean()
df['MA_5'] = df['Adj Close'].rolling(window=5).mean()
```

*Note 2*: Above I assume, that it is `df['Adj Close'][i:i+3]` in the for-loop (not `ds['Adj Close'][i:i+3]`, same for the next line)